# Change Bootstrap Carousel Indicator to Right and Bottom Tabs

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is the example carousel template from bootstrap website
[image]
What I want to do is make the dots in the yellow circle from image above becoming right tabs like the image below
[image]
and when the screen is narrow, the tabs move to the bottom of the carousel
[image]
how to do that?

**EDIT :**

with this code :

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div style="background-color: red;" class="slider col-lg-10">
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img class="first-slide img-responsive center-block" src="assets/img/underconstruction.jpg" alt="First slide">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>Example headline.</h1>
            <p>Note: If you're viewing this page via a <code>file://</code> URL, the "next" and "previous" Glyphicon buttons on the left and right might not load/display properly due to web browser security rules.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>
          </div><!-- carousel-caption -->
        </div><!-- container -->
      </div><!-- item active -->
      <div class="item">
        <img class="second-slide" src="assets/img/underconstruction.jpg" alt="Second slide">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
            <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
          </div><!-- carousel-caption -->
        </div><!-- container -->
      </div><!-- item -->
      <div class="item">
        <img class="third-slide" src="assets/img/underconstruction.jpg" alt="Third slide">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
            <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a></p>
          </div><!-- carousel-caption -->
        </div><!-- container -->
      </div><!-- item -->
    </div><!-- carousel-inner -->
  </div><!-- slider col-lg-10 -->

  <div data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" style="background-color: blue;" class="tabs-vertical col-lg-2 visible-lg">TAB 1</div>
  <div data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" style="background-color: yellow;" class="tabs-vertical col-lg-2 visible-lg">TAB 2</div>
  <div data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" style="background-color: cyan;" class="tabs-vertical col-lg-2 visible-lg">TAB 3</div>

  <div data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" style="background-color: blue;" class="tabs-horizontal col-xs-4 hidden-lg">TAB 1</div>
  <div data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" style="background-color: yellow;" class="tabs-horizontal col-xs-4 hidden-lg">TAB 2</div>
  <div data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" style="background-color: cyan;" class="tabs-horizontal col-xs-4 hidden-lg">TAB 3</div>
</div><!-- carousel slide -->
```

I managed to get this on wide screen :
[image]

and this on narrow screen :
[image]

thanks to Justinas for that.

but the vertical tabs still not fill the rest of the space below it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Bootstrap grid system. On wide screen show vertical tabs, hide horizontal tabs; on small - hide vertical tabs, show horizontal.

To hide some element, use `hidden-[xs/sm/md/lg]` or `visible-[xs/sm/md/lg]` helper classes.

```
<div class="slider col-lg-10"></div>
<div class="tabs-vertical col-lg-2 visible-lg"></div>
<div class="tabs-horizontal col-xs-12 hidde-lg"></div>
```

Comment: could you please write the example code and where to place it?

Comment: @rizkynggakool 1. How it's not working? 2. What you have done testing why it's not working?

Comment: I remove all the elements in the body, and then insert your skeleton code, the page is blank

Comment: @rizkynggakool Maybe because HTML elements without content is not visible? Have you at least tried coding HTML before?